# Github - getting not found error when trying to publish package to npm

Tags: github-actions, npm-publish

I'm trying to publish a new package to npm, public.

I have the following workflow:

```
# This workflow will run tests using node and then publish a package to GitHub 

Packages when a release is created
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/publishing-nodejs-packages

name: Node.js Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:

  publish-npm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 14
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm login
      - run: npm config set access public
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.npm_token}}
```

But I get the following error:

```
npm notice 
npm notice   @orgname/pdf-image@1.2.2
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 135B    Dockerfile                       
npm notice 135B    Dockerfile12                     
npm notice 1.1kB   LICENSE                          
npm notice 6.8kB   index.js                         
npm notice 5.9kB   tests/test-main.js               
npm notice 530B    package.json                     
npm notice 2.1kB   README.md                        
npm notice 325.2kB tests/test.pdf                   
npm notice 1.1kB   .github/workflows/node.js.yml    
npm notice 664B    .github/workflows/npm-publish.yml
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @orgname/pdf-image                    
npm notice version:       1.2.2                                   
npm notice package size:  322.6 kB                                
npm notice unpacked size: 343.6 kB                                
npm notice shasum:        d362e3a6c95d12b2329ed608495c45580bb8de15
npm notice integrity:     sha512-OpurprtbmR7By[...]V553ykjYtaOrA==
npm notice total files:   10                                      
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@orgname%2fpdf-image - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@orgname/pdf-image@1.2.2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

Please advise how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you need to replace `@orgname` with your actual org name? Or did you add that to obfuscate your org name for SO?

Comment: obfuscation purposes only.

Comment: does the same command work locally?

Comment: did not try it, thought about it but wanted the first tag to be released from workflow.

Answer (score 1):

`npm login` is unnecessary here.
You need to do 3 steps to make it work:

1. Config the job on your `yml` file:

   ```
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v3
     - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
       with:
         node-version: 16
         registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
     - run: npm ci
     - run: npm run build
     - run: npm publish
       env:
         NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
   ```
2. Define `NPM_TOKEN` access token in your `npmjs` account under access tokens, make sure it's an **automation** token:

[image]

3. Copy this token and define him in your GitHub repository:

   [image]